# Formidable forms with WordPress being tripled

Tags: css, forms, plugins, wordpress

I'm using the Formidable plugin to create forms in WordPress. However, when I insert the form onto a page, it is tripled - that is, three versions of the form appear, one after another. Has anyone had this problem? What could possibly be causing it? Could it be in my CSS or the form's CSS? Maybe in JavaScript?

Comment: are you using shortcode to insert the form?

Comment: @Trey: yes, I'm using the form's ID ("[formidable key=ag0d0m]").

Comment: @thirtydot: I didn't think so, and I've confirmed that it's not the Formidable CSS either. Problem is, there are about 10 different JavaScript files attached to the site (I inherited it from a previous developer) and they've all been minified.

Comment: Have you successfully used formidable before?

Comment: Yes - In fact, all the other forms on the site are working just fine.

Comment: Got a link you'd like to share with us?

Comment: I would but it's not visible to the public. Sorry!

Comment: @daysrunaway Try switching themes to TwentyTen or something equally basic and see if the form works that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not CSS as you say, use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) with Firefox, or in Chrome or Safari or IE8, use the developer tools to see what javascript is loading on your site, i.e., and what scripts, which are duplicates. Those tools will also show javascript errors in case some scripts - core WP scripts or plugin scripts - are colliding.

If they're minified, look for a plugin that is doing that. If not, de-minify them: http://jsbeautifier.org/